# Spring Integration doesn't synchronize with FTP mainframe system

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to sycronize an FTP folder with a local directory. This FTP server is running on z/OS, it's a mainframe with he MVS operating system.

So far I've had a lot of problems even to manage to connect to the folder I needed because this system doesn't have a "normal" folder system.

This is what I've done to change to the working directory where my files are:

```
public class DefaultFtpHostSessionFactory extends DefaultFtpSessionFactory {
    protected void postProcessClientAfterConnect(FTPClient ftp) throws IOException {
        ftp.changeToParentDirectory();
        ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("E377D.");
    }
}
```

Now I've defined an input-channel-adapter:

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter 
        id="ljFtpInbound"
        channel="ljFtpChannel"
        session-factory="ljCachingSessionFactory"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        filename-pattern="*"
        remote-directory="*"
        remote-file-separator=""
        charset="UTF-8"
        auto-startup="true"
        preserve-timestamp="false"
        local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toUpperCase()"
        temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
        local-directory="/tmp/">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

As you can notice the remote directory is "*", that's for listing the directory, at least is the only way I've managed to do it.

But when FtpInboundFileSynchronizer tries to synchronize the folder I get an error because when it tries to copy the file the path is build with:

```
String remoteFilePath = remoteDirectoryPath + remoteFileSeparator + remoteFileName;
```

Which in my case would be "ASTERISK" + "BLANK" + "REMOTE_FILE_NAME", because I had to use "*" as the remote-directory, so it doesn't find the file.

¿Do you know if I can not to set the remote-directory (which I tried but didn't achieve)? Or there is another way to synchronized this weird FTP system.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

> Starting with version 4.3, The `remote-directory/remote-directory-expression` attributes can be omitted assuming `null`. In this case, according to the FTP protocol, the Client working directory is used as a default remote directory.

That means you should try to upgrade to Spring Integration 4.3 and remove that strange `*` at all.